# Chainable boolean flags - what are they called?

Tags: flags

Frameworks I've seen before allow to pass a chain of multiple constants via a single parameter like So, I believe:

```
foo(FLAG_A | FLAG_B | FLAG_C);
```

They act like boolean so the function knows which flags have been given.

Now I want to implement something like that.

What is this concept called?

Comment: Don’t know what that’s called actually or whether there is a specific name for that, but the basic principle is simple. They all have integer values with only one specific bit set each, so that “joining” them with a logical bitwise OR results in a value that has _several_ of those distinct bits set. And on the “receiving” end, a bitwise AND helps to determine whether a specific bit was set in that value.

Answer (score 0):

It's based on binary-ORing. Normally, each of the symbolic constants will be just one distinct bit, e.g., as in:

```
enum {
   FLAG_A = 1,
   FLAG_B = 1<<1,
   FLAG_C = 1<<2,
};
```

so that you can than add them together with `|`, test for each individual one with `&` and subtract two such flag sets  with `& ~`.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net, these are defined by an `enum` using the FlagsAttribute:

```
[Flags()]
public enum Foo
{
     Bit1 = 1,
     Bit2 = 2,
     Bit4 = 4,
     Bit8 = 8,
     etc.
 }

// Or define using explicit binary syntax
[Flags()]
public enum Foo
{
     Bit1 = 0b_0000_0001,
     Bit2 = 0b_0000_0010,
     Bit4 = 0b_0000_0100,
     Bit8 = 0b_0000_,
     etc.
 }
```

And to utilise:

```
SomeFunction(Foo.Bit1 | Foo.Bit4 | etc);
```

I would suggest that your current name (**Flags**) seems to be the most appropriate definition, at least in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently "flags and bitmasks" are the right keywords to find more about this. "Flags" alone didn't before. Great thanks for the explanatory answers nevertheless!